# can't run different instance of tor on separate DataDirecotry due to permission error

Tags: configuration, exit-relays, linux, error, directory

I'm trying to run different instances of tor simultaneously. One without exit node set and one with set exit note. To do so, I have to change the port and change the DataDirectory as well (Correct?). But running `tor -f /etc/tor/torrcGB` cause this log:

```
May 28 16:15:16.473 [notice] Tor 0.3.3.6 (git-7dd0813e783ae16e) running on Linux with Libevent 2.1.8-stable, OpenSSL 1.1.0h, Zlib 1.2.11, Liblzma 5.2.4, and Libzstd N/A.
May 28 16:15:16.473 [notice] Tor can't help you if you use it wrong! Learn how to be safe at https://www.torproject.org/download/download#warning
May 28 16:15:16.473 [notice] Read configuration file "/etc/tor/torrcGB".
May 28 16:15:16.475 [warn] ControlPort is open, but no authentication method has been configured.  This means that any program on your computer can reconfigure your Tor.  That's bad!  You should upgrade your Tor controller as soon as possible.
May 28 16:15:16.475 [notice] Scheduler type KIST has been enabled.
May 28 16:15:16.475 [notice] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9060
May 28 16:15:16.475 [notice] Opening Control listener on 127.0.0.1:9061
May 28 16:15:16.475 [warn] Error creating directory /var/lib/torGB: Permission denied
May 28 16:15:16.475 [warn] Failed to parse/validate config: Couldn't create private data directory "/var/lib/torGB"
May 28 16:15:16.475 [err] Reading config failed--see warnings above.
```

here is my `/etc/tor/torrcGB`:

```
Log notice syslog

# To be able have different tor
SocksPort 9060
ControlPort 9061
DataDirectory /var/lib/torGB

# Set for GB exit node
ExitNodes {uk},{gb},{io},{vg}
StrictNodes 1

UseBridges 1
ClientTransportPlugin obfs4 exec /usr/bin/obfs4proxy managed


bridge obfs4 35.162.230.20:9443 CA8D14F8C289B13AD9D1D22262744EBE4761DD15 cert=H39+NPm6vxyimJFDbbhuhq8AFaGZ2Uw1OOMPAX1QiR5+M5YvLgcRdEOpyfDIwqiLX1KdRw iat-mode=0
```

I tried creating `/var/lib/torGB/` directory myself, set the owner to `tor` and even copy the `/var/lib/tor/` and rename it (and change the owner)...all these efforts didn't work.

Comment: If you're on Debian/Ubuntu or a shitty rip-off of one of those like Mint then use `tor-instance-create` https://www.torservers.net/wiki/setup/server#multiple_tor_processes

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities I know of which may cause this problem:

1. Tor is running as non-root user and permissions on /var/lib do not allow that user to create directory. As you tried to fix it by hand this is probably not that case.
2. You have selinux (or similar technology) enabled and it gets in a way. Try to disable it (setenforce 0) and see if this helps. If so - you may need to manually adjust selinux context on the files and directories to let tor to run or just disable it altogether (not recommended).

Comment: The first item might be the case since my `/var/lib/tor` folder and all contents belong to `tor` user (a built-in user I think). Regarding the second, I don't have selinux.